# Jsp vs core java?

Tags: jsp, applet, content-management-system, easy-install, java

So i want to make an application or a UI software that could be used in stores where the shopkeeper would be able to know about his supply of products.
This would all be offline and i would like to keep it as simple as possible to run for like a layman 
Example: 
The software would have the capability to store new products coming into the store and then also delete those when bought. It will show the store keeper about his profit n loss and the product quantities left and how much needs to be added as per a default value.Mysql wil be used às databse.
This would be all in java programming only.

So what shout I use: java apps or make jsp pages(website kind of) or any other way possible.

Keeping in mind that the owner can only start the program by clicking an icon and knows only to type on computer (basic layman things nothing else)

Just started making programs so dont know much abt wht would be difficult for a layman.

Also if possible, plz let me know if i could use applets in such case.

Comment: *"Just started making programs so.."* ,,put this entire project aside for a while, till you get more experience. *"..let me know if i could use applets in such case."* No. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I'm actually from accounts side and got an interest in coding from the past year......trying to develop small projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this with just jsp/Servlets.

1. Once you complete developing your website. make a war file of it.
2. Then on client's machine setup database and tomcat 8 server.
3. Go to service and set tomcat service to start with windows.
4. Then make a Browser Shortcut on clicking which your website will directly open in browser.

This is also possible with Servlets but I would re-command you to go with Web site only. In applets Handling event's may become hard.

Comment: THANK YOU so much for the reply. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: 1 more thing: If I make a JAVA APPLICATION on netbeans IDE and set up the database on client's system. Then make a JAR file for the client to just double click on the icon and start. It would be like a stand-alone application and wont require the use of browser. Like explained here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFP0hG0U9tE                                 Would it work ? Or what do u suggest?

Comment: Sounds like you want a desktop application, not a jsp application, you could always have an embedded webserver in a program and have everything use a browser in the program to access it, but at that point you're using the wrong tool for the job

Comment: ya, was talking abt desktop app only in the comment section here..............actually I wanted a suggestion as to what kind of program should I make : JSP one(web-based using tomcat) , OR, a normal DESKTOP APP(using netbeans) ???? What would be better for a normal store owner to understand and use AND even I dont have to make much efforts on it (setting up servers, handling maintenance n all  afterwards) ????

Comment: Making a desktop application will become a hard thing for you as they don't provide easiness in setting view and your view will become very hard to manage everything. I would advise you to make a website as if in case if you want to run your application in multiple devices in same network or different then there will be very less number of configuration you will need to make and it will also be platform independent in terms of computer and mobile. As website can be opened from any device but App can't be.